# TabBarController disappear after presenting a new view programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

After searching a lot for a solution to my problem and didn't found a correct answer I post the problem: I have two viewControllers company and companyDetail when I execute

```
CompanyViewDetail *cDetail = [[CompanyViewDetail alloc] init];
  [self presentViewController:cDetail animated:YES completion:nil];
```

it navigate to companyDetailViewController but the tabBar that I created in AppDelegate  disappear, here is the code:

```
tabBars = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
 self.window.rootViewController = tabBars;
 self.tabBars.view.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
 [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: Use `showViewController` instead

Comment: When you **present** a view controller, it is shown *over* the current context, which is the Tab Bar Controller. If you want it shown only over the view displayed in the current tab, you need to load it as a child view controller and add its view as a subview.

Comment: every sub-page for the tab-bar controller should be assigned to the `viewControllers` array.

Comment: why I will do that when I created the tabBar inside appDelegate and gave it the rootViewController to be always displayed